# Create a batch file to join two files with *similar names* and same extensions [Windows]

Tags: windows, ffmpeg, batch

I'm currently attempting to take files:

```
example.mkv           // This is the source with audio/subs
example-Encoded.mkv   // This is video only/encoded source
```

And set up a script. I have made a successful script but after it pulls the first two it tries to pull more, while it does get the remux done it throws an error because it's looking for a version of the file named `example-Encoded-Encode.mkv`

Here is the script I'm using:

```
mkdir MUXED

FOR %%a IN ("*.mkv") DO ffmpeg -i "%%a" -i "%%~na-Encoded.mkv" ^
-map 1:v:0 c:v:0 copy -disposition:v:0 default -metadata:s:v:0 title="Example" ^
-map 0:a:0 -c:a:0 copy -disposition:a:0 default -metadata:s:a:0 title="DD 2.0" ^
-map 0:a:1 -c:a:1 copy -metadata:s:s:0 title="Commentary" ^
-map 0:s:0 -c:s:0 copy -metadata:s:s:0 title="English (SRT)" ^
-map 0:s:1 -c:s:1 copy -metadata:s:s:1 title="English (VobSub)" ^
"MUXED\%%~na.mkv"

pause
```

I can do same file names by converting the encoded files to a mp4 container, as they are just encoded video. However, I feel like there is a way to do this properly without me having to change the containers first!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this listing only for `*-Encoded.mkv` files in your for loop:

```all-bat
@echo off && setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

cd/d "%~dp0" & set "_x=-Encoded" && 2>nul mkdir .\MUXED

for /f tokens^=* %%i in ('dir /b /on /a:-d "*!_x!.mkv"
')do set "_i=%%~nxi!" && cmd.exe /v:on /c ffmpeg.exe -i "!_i:%_x%=!" -i "%%~nxi" ^
-map 1:v:0 -c:v:0 copy -disposition:v:0 default -metadata:s:v:0 title="Example" ^
-map 0:a:0 -c:a:0 copy -disposition:a:0 default -metadata:s:a:0 title="DD 2.0" ^
-map 0:s:1 -c:s:1 copy -metadata:s:s:1 title="English (VobSub)" ^
-map 0:s:0 -c:s:0 copy -metadata:s:s:0 title="English (SRT)" ^
-map 0:a:1 -c:a:1 copy -metadata:s:s:0 title="Commentary" ^
".\MUXED\%%~ni.mkv" -hide_banner -v error -stats 

%__APPDIR__%timeout.exe -1 & endlocal
```

- Some further reading:

  [√] **[Dir](https://ss64.com/nt/dir.html)**

  [√] **[CD/CHDir](https://ss64.com/nt/cd.html)**

  [√] **[MD/MKDir](https://ss64.com/nt/md.html)**

  [√] **[For Loop](https://ss64.com/nt/for.html)**

  [√] **[For /F Loop](https://ss64.com/nt/for_f.html)**

  [√] **[Redirection](https://www.robvanderwoude.com/redirection.php)**

  [√] **[CMD/Bat String Manipulation](https://www.dostips.com/DtTipsStringManipulation.php)**

  [√] **[Conditional Execution || && ...](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-conditional.html)**

Comment: Code works perfectly. Now can you show me where I can learn this? As my script looks a lot more basic then yours and obviously wasn't doing the trick. 

I'd love to learn how to easily make my own scripts. Thanks!!

Comment: @JessieWilson For any question you can use here, superuser.com and command docs/help: dostips.com, computerhope.com, ss64.com, also this [MS CMD Ref.pdf](https://download.microsoft.com/download/5/8/9/58911986-D4AD-4695-BF63-F734CD4DF8F2/ws-commands.pdf)

Comment: @JessieWilson My script looks like yours compared to Dino and other Lot around here ...! It is important to learn, don't be shy with your codes, with time and experience they get better on their own ..

Comment: @JessieWilson There are only 2 types of scripts, the ones that work and the ones don't work yet!

Comment: I really appreciate the help. This is my first time using this site and it's awesome! So helpful! :) 

It looks like I have a lot to learn. I don't know where to start.

Comment: @JessieWilson Try to start visiting some questions about ffmpeg + cmd/bat or anything else that has an affinity with you, also about converting audio and video by cmd/bat/command line ... When trying to do something, try searching line by line, command by command on the web, if you can't, in research you have already learned some things ... so ask, in time, you can solve your own problems, it is natural.